# XPath do not show duplicate values (recursive query)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

In my situation I have a query that has a recursive part (.//). In my results of the XML-XSLT (using Xpath), I would like to see only unique values. I work with Altova Stylevision to set up this XSLT.

My XML:

```
<Subject>
<Subject>
        <L2 Name="Asset 1">
          <IDR3 Name="IDR A" />
        </L2>
        <L2 Name="Asset 2">
          <IDR3 Name="IDR B" />
        </L2>
</Subject>  
<Subject>
        <L2 Name="Asset 3">
          <IDR3 Name="IDR B" />
        </L2>
        <L2 Name="Asset 4">
          <IDR3 Name="IDR B" />
        </L2>
    <Subject>
            <L2 Name="Asset 5">
              <IDR3 Name="IDR A" />
            </L2>
            <L2 Name="Asset 2">
              <IDR3 Name="IDR B" />
            </L2>
    </Subject>      
</Subject>          
<Subject>
    <Subject>
        <Subject>
            <L2 Name="Asset 7">
              <IDR3 Name="IDR C" />
            </L2>
            <L2 Name="Asset 8">
              <IDR3 Name="IDR B" />
            </L2>
        </Subject>
    </Subject>      
</Subject>
```

The whole "Subject" thing is a recursive part. I would like to have the following outcome:

- IDR A
- IDR B
- IDR C

The string I've used to set up the initial XSLT:

```
.//Subject/L2/IDR3/@Name
```

I have tried multiple solutions with `preceding::sibling` and `distinct-values`, but I can't figure this one out since I have to deal with recursive-ness (downwards/upwards). I really hope someone can help me with this one.

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
distinct-values(//IDR3/@Name)
```

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDmh